# How to integrate Asp Net Core Identity with a custom user provider?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm writing a web api server and i need to protect controllers actions with Identity authorization.

It's an internal business application and users are managed from another service, so I just have to login&logout through thats external dll.

I have an external service which returns claims and role for a given username, but I'm totally lost on how to "wrap" this with identity.

I have my implementation of IdentityUser and an implementation of IUserStore<> with just what I need, but I can't find any tutorial on how to create a custom signinmanager and a usermanager (for my situation) and I don't even know if I really need those or how to link them all together in the startup.cs

Any hint will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

As part of implementing custom `IUserStore` you should also implement  **`IUserLoginStore`** interface (as well as other relevant ones you might need).

This [Overview of Custom Storage Providers for `ASP.NET Identity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/extensibility/overview-of-custom-storage-providers-for-aspnet-identity) will help to figure out the technical details and understand what is/should be involved into play.